# How to use IFS in a smtp email

Tags: linux, bash, smtp

I have a text file with that contains

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

When I send a email using SMTP the format shows

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

I want it to display vertically.
Here is what I have.

```
file=$(cat file1.txt)
echo -e "here are the numbers $file" | mail -S smtp=xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx -S from blahblah@blah.com -s "subject" user1@xxxx.xxxx
```

I tried applying `IFS=$'\t'` in different ways but no luck. I am not interested in using `mailx`.

Comment: `mailx` is the standard command for  sending email. There exist a few commands called `mail`, but they are very different from each other and don't follow any standard. Can you pinpoint which implementation (and version) yours is?

Comment: Sorry I’m writing this from my phone. In the script I am using single and double quotes from the laptop keyboard.

Comment: The email sends fine without any issues. The problem is the format of the txt file.

Comment: With what client are you _reading_ the message? If it's Outlook, it's the client that has stripped the newlines.

Comment: Yes outlook (ms 365 proplus)

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case it's really really hard - see https://www.google.com/search?q=outlook+removes+newlines

Comment: I have emailed other things before from /proc/meminfo. That showed up fine.

Comment: For one, it's definitely not about IFS, since you quoted the variable, as is right and proper. About Outlook, did it have some feature to show the message "raw"? Can you go there and see what it looks like vs another message where you leave the newlines out intentionally? One of the [links about that](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/287816/line-breaks-are-removed-in-posts-made-in-plain-text-format-in-outlook) mention sending the message in HTML, so in principle you could add some minimal HTML boilerplate to do just that (though I'll be damned for even suggesting this).

Comment: do you know that linux line endings LF are not recognized in windows? try `${file//$'\n'/$'\r\n'}`

Comment: @Ilkkachu it's how I ended up working around exactly this same problem